# Chat avatar list places single avatar on last row instead of previous row

Tags: discussion, chat, design

I've noticed on numerous occasions the list of avatars in a chatroom will display like the following when a new user joins the room.

[image: chat screenshot]

As you can see there is plenty of space for the avatar to be on the previous row, but for some reason it is being pushed into its own row needlessly. It doesn't always happen, but it is quite frequent.

Refreshing the page fixes the issue. Is anyone else experiencing the same issue?

and again...

[image: chat screenshot 2]

Wohoo, double score this time:

[image]

Comment: What browser are you on?

Comment: @PeeHaa埽: It's embarrassing, but Firefox =o(

Comment: Right(?left) justified images o_0

Comment: This could possibly be a Firefox bug, as those elements are just an _inline-block_ list. Unless something weird happens around the 32nd user...

Answer (score -1):

It's most likely a glitch, as I don't think that anyone would have intended for that to happen. I've never seen this on Safari v6.0.2 (1 patch behind, whatever).

Comment: (cough) should be a comment (cough) Hm, odd. I'm not getting this either in Firefox.